# why is recaptcha.IsValid always returns True

Tags: asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

why is recaptcha.IsValid always returns True?

```
    Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatingUser
    Dim Captcha As RecaptchaControl = CType(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("recaptcha1"), RecaptchaControl)
    If Not Captcha.IsValid Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `Captcha.Validate()` before `Captcha.IsValid`

```
    Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatingUser
    Dim Captcha As RecaptchaControl = CType(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("recaptcha1"), RecaptchaControl)
    Captcha.Validate()
    If Not Captcha.IsValid Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```